# Book recommendation: first year economics course

Tags: microeconomics

Can anyone help me find a nice introduction (possibly popular economics) into the field of black market economics.

Comment: Why not this one? The authors are renowned:  https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/shadow-economy/ECA54B3ED2F921624A47F7CBC26E7237. You will also easily find discussion papers by these authors.

Comment: @Bertrand: Why not convert your comment into an answer?

Comment: @Herr K., well I feel that it is a bit too easy to be considered as an answer (and was also afraid that it was not relevant)